# Параметры в MySQL запросе не заменяются C#

Tags: c#, mysql

В запрос не подставляются параметры, делаю так:

```
using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO users (name, email, password) VALUES ('@username', '@email', '@password')", this.mc))
{
    command.Prepare();
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", this.username);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", this.email);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", this.password);
    int numRows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if (numRows > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

В итоге в базу добавляются значения так, как они есть в строке запроса изначально, т.е. @username, @email, @password и т.д. 
Что я делаю не так? Прогуглил, везде делают так, в некоторых местах пишут вместо '@' - ':' или '?' - так тоже пробовал, то же самое. Пробовал при добавлении параметра указывать без символа, т.е.

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", this.password);
```

Так тоже не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите одинарные кавычки вокруг параметров в SQL запросе.

*Update*

> значения им не придавал

Параметры в SQL - это как переменные в C#.

Аналог запроса с кавычками - как у Вас:

```
string a = "This is value of variable a.";
string b = "Add something to variable a - 'a'";
```

Аналог запроса без кавычек:

```
string a = "This is value of variable a.";
string b = $"Add something to variable a - {a}";
```

Comment: и правда, спасибо. В решениях которые гуглил - кавычки использовались, и там у автора якобы все работало, поэтому значения им не придавал

Comment: @Razorik если ответ помог, то ставьте галку и upvote.